# iOS Swift SpriteKit didEndContact not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

in my app(game) i need to detect contact with water and run action(withKey) while my Node is under water,im doing that with `didBeginContact` and `Update` method. But when i move my Node(with touches) from water im using `didEndContact` to detect whether Node is outof water and stop previous action(withKey) and it could be all fine but sometimes `didEndContact` not stoping action and do not detect (using `print("EndContact")`) that contact is ended.

Cheking contact between to nodes:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    if let node1 = contact.bodyA.node
    {
        let entityNode = node1 as! Entity
        entityNode.collideWith(contact.bodyB, contact: contact)
    }

    if let node2 = contact.bodyB.node
    {
        let entityNode = node2 as! Entity
        entityNode.collideWith(contact.bodyA, contact: contact)
    }
}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    if let node1 = contact.bodyA.node
    {
        let entityNode = node1 as! Entity
        entityNode.collideEndedWith(contact.bodyB, contact: contact)
    }

    if let node2 = contact.bodyB.node
    {
        let entityNode = node2 as! Entity
        entityNode.collideEndedWith(contact.bodyA, contact: contact)
    }

}
```

`Entity` is subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, where i declare physics bitmask and so-on. I got `Player` class and `Enemy` class based on `Entity`. In my `Player` class i got functions that run some code when `didBeginContact` and `didEndContact` triggers

```
override func collideWith(body: SKPhysicsBody, contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    if let enemy = body.node as? Enemy
    {
        contactingWater = true
        self.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(1.1, duration: 0.2), withKey: "action")
    }
}

override func collideEndedWith(body: SKPhysicsBody, contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    if let enemy = body.node as? Enemy
    {
        contactingWater = false
        self.removeActionWithKey("action")
    } 
}
override func update(delta: CFTimeInterval){
}
```

Also i update my 'Player' on 'MainScene' in `Update` method. It seems to work fine but as i said sometimes `didEndContact` do not trigger

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 
    {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime

    player?.update(dt)
}
```

I noticed that this"sometimes" occurs
when i move Node into the water and when move back remove my finger ith stil thinks that im in contact with water. Ill be glad to any sugestion, cause im very new in programing) thx

Comment: Can you list some code that can replicate the issue?

Comment: But "sometimes didEndContact not stoping action" how can you know it if the action is during just 0.2 seconds?

Comment: Since im updating my Player class (that contains collideWith and collideEndedWith func with scalling action with 0,2sec) with deltatime in MainScene, that action is repeated until player contacting Water and when i move player from water action is removed, bud as i said sometimes action isnt removed when contact ended